# where should I run templates.html in webpy?

Tags: python

I'm learning webpy and I study http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/tutorial site.
I have problem and don't understand where (which directory ) should we write html file and how run it? I should run .py file only o what?
If someone introduce some book or web sit about webpy I will be happy.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consult the [official](http://webpy.org/) site. Also read [cookbook](http://webpy.org/cookbook/) for basic and advanced examples. Follow [this](http://webpy.org/tutorial3.en) to get started. Hope that helps!!